# jQuery, obtained variable from HTML class in WordPress loop, how to edit that variable?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress theme, and during the loop, it puts the_ID on each class.  So, I have like a couple posts with the class "teamPost-138", "teamPost-222", etc...

I have stored that "teamPost-###" in a jQuery variable, and now I need to take off the "teamPost-" part.  Is there a way I can cut that in the variable, or can I just select the number part from the class in the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on what your doing, is it just to assign the number to the variable instead of the teamPost-###?

Below is some code that you may be able to repurpose.  For every element that has a class starting with 'teamPost-' it logs (to the firebug console) the number from their class.  The index of isused to negate issues of the item having multiple classes.

e.g.

```
$('[class^=teamPost-]').each(function () {
    var class = $(this).attr('class');
    var numStart = class.indexOf('teamPost-')+9;
    console.log(class.substring(numStart,numStart+3));
});
```

If its simply stripping the start of the variable then you just need the strubgstring part:

```
'teamPost-123'.substring(9); // equals '123'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#teamPost-###').attr('id', '###');
```

Changes the ID of the selected item.